Finding the number of integers between $3456$ and $6000$ that have all unique digits

Finding the number of integers between $3456$ and $6000$ that have all unique digits.

How would one go about solving this question? Here is my approach:
Case $1$: Numbers of the type $34XX$
3 valid numbers: $3457, 3458, 3459$
Case $2$: Numbers of the type $3AXX$, where $A=5,6,7,8,9$
$A$ has $5$ choices, and the number $3$ cannot be used, so $XX$ has $(10-2)(10-3)=56$ choices. Total $= 5*56 = \textbf{280}$
ㅤ
ㅤ
Case $3$: Numbers of the type $BXXX$, where $B=4,5$
$B$ has $2$ choices, and $B$ cannot be used in any of the $Xs$, so $XXX$ has $(10-1)(10-2)(10-3)  = 9 * 8 * 7 = 504$ choices. Total $= 2 * 504 = \textbf{1008}$.
ㅤ
ㅤ
Overall, the number of integers is $3+280+1008=1291$, however the correct answer appears to be $1319$.

First of all, in the range $4000$ to $4999$, we have $9\cdot 8\cdot 7$ ways to choose the hundreds, tens, and ones digit. Same for $5000$ to $5999$.
For $3500$ to $3599$, there are $8\cdot 7$ ways. Same for $3600$ to $3699$, $3700$ to $3799$, $3800$ to $8599$, and $3900$ to $3999$.
From $3460$ to $3469$ there are $7$ ways, same for $3470$ to $3479$ , $3480$ to $3489$ , and $3490$ to $3499$ .
From $3456$ to $3459$, there are $4$ ways.
Thus our answer is
$$9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 2 + 8\cdot 7\cdot 5 + 7\cdot 4+4 = 1320$$
It isn't very clear if we include $3456$ in the count, but I did here.

Thank you, although the final answer would be 1329 since 3456 isn't to be counted, although I do agree the original question was a bit ambiguous.

The author could have avoided the ambiguity by asking for the numbers between $3455$ and $6000$ that have distinct digits, in which case the answer would have been $1320$.

You've made a good start, but you're missing handling the integers of the form $34CX$ where $C = 6, 7, 8, 9$. Here, $C$ has $4$ possible values, with each $X$ having $10 - 3 = 7$ choices since $C$, $3$ and $4$ can't be used. Thus, there are $4 \times 7 = 28$ additional values. Adding this to your result gives $1291 + 28 = 1319$, i.e., the official answer.

Note item #$5$ in the definition of between as a preposition states the range is exclusive:

If something is between two amounts or ages, it is greater or older than the first one and smaller or younger than the second one.

However, my experience is that it's different when numeric quantities are requested, e.g., a sentence like "Pick a number between $1$ and $10$." usually means an inclusive range, i.e., both $1$ and $10$ are allowed choices. Thus, it's not clear what's meant from the problem wording so, as suggested in Razzi's answer, perhaps $3456$ should also be included in the result, for a total of $1320$ instead.
